# Tablepress change cursor only for rows with links

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using Tablepress for Wordpress to show tables on my website, some of the rows in the tables have an image in the last column with a link.

I am using Jquery to make rows with links clickable but now I only want the cursor to change to a hand for rows that have a link in the last column.

The css code I use to change the cursor us:

```
.tablepress tr:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Would anyone know how to only change the cursor to a hand for rows that contain a link in the last column?

Many thanks

Comment: If you are using Jquery to make rows clickable then use it to add a class on hover too with the cursor pointer

Comment: Thank you, can you maybe me give me some pointers on where to insert this in the current code? This is what I currently use:

   <script>// <![CDATA[
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.tablepress-id-3').on( 'click', 'tr', function( event ) {
        var $a;
        if ( $( event.target ).is( "img" ) ) {
          return;
        }
        $a = $(this).find('a').last();
        if ( $a.length ) {
          window.open($a.attr('href'), "_blank");
        }
      } );
    });
    // ]]></script>